# Add styles to headings (text bold and backgroundcolor) of a Treeview Table - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have this little Tkinter GUI where I have a table. I want to make the text bold in the headings and also change its background color. I know that we can do this by ttk.Style() and configure but nothing is changing in the table. It's still looking plain or am I doing this wrong.

Please help.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.state('zoomed')
treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse')
treev.place(x= 600, y= 200, width= 350, height=350)

treev["columns"] = ('1', '2')
treev['show'] = 'headings'

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('mytreeview.Headings', background='gray', font=('Arial Bold', 10))


ID = [1,2,3,4,5]
Names = ['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim']

treev.column("1", width = 100, anchor ='c')
treev.column("2", width = 100, anchor ='c')

treev.heading("1", text ="ID")
treev.heading("2", text ="Names")


for x, y in zip(ID, Names):
    treev.insert("", 'end', values =(x, y))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse',style='mytreeview')` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh wait let me try it.

Comment: i am a getting error saying : tkinter.TclError: Layout mytreeview not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure an style you need a layout that is called so:

```
style.layout('my.Treeview',
             [('Treeview.field', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'border': '1', 'children': [
                 ('Treeview.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                     ('Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})
                     ]})
                 ]})
              ])
```

This code makes a new layout called *my.Treeview* and copies the data of *Treeview*.
Then, after you have a layout created with that name you can configure it with:

```
style.configure('my.Treeview.Heading', background='gray', font=('Arial Bold', 10))
```

and dont forget to use that style on the widget you like with:

```
treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse',style='my.Treeview')
```

Comment: Thanks mate.. this really helped a lot :)