# How do I use ttk.style on ttk.scale the right way?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to customize a ttk.Scale using a ttk.Style. I don't really know, how to apply my Style to my Scale. Right now I am using this:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure(".", background="#505050")
scale = ttk.Scale(self.root, from_ = 100, to = 0, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
```

This works just fine, but I don't really understand, whats going on with the "." .

I also tried something like this:

```py
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("myStyle", background="#505050")
scale = ttk.Scale(self.root, from_ = 100, to = 0, orient=tk.VERTICAL, style="myStyle")
```

But I am getting this error:

`Layout Vertical.myStyle.TScale not found`

This seems to work for buttons for example, but apparently not for scales:

```py
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("myStyle", background="#505050")
scale = ttk.Scale(self.root, from_ = 100, to = 0, orient=tk.VERTICAL, style="myStyle.TScale")
```

But I am also getting the same error.

All in all I am pretty confused on how to handle ttk.Style with ttk.Scale.

**How do I apply a ttk.Style to a ttk.Scale the right way?**

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65537997/13629335)

Comment: This is not true, as I said before, I got it to work with the code first mentioned in my question.

Comment: You should use something like `style.configure("myStyle.Vertical.TScale", background="#505050")`, then `scale = ttk.Scale(..., style="myStyle.Vertical.TScale")`.

Comment: This works as well, thanks. But why can't I simply use a name like "myStyle"?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put the "TScale" and it will work

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

window = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TScale", background="#505050")
scale = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, value=0, orient="vertical", style="TScale")
scale.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're styling a horizontal slider, use

`style.configure('myStyle.Horizontal.TScale', background="red")`

If you're styling a vertical slider, use

`style.configure('myStyle.Vertical.TScale', background="red")`

Now myStyle acts as a custom style and can be attached to a slider to modify the looks of the respective slider object (Horizontal or Vertical).